# Make extensions for kotlin arrays

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to make a library thing which provides specific extensions for collections/collection-like containers in kotlin:

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }

fun String.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.toList().extendEntries(length)
fun <T> Array<T>.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun CharArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun BooleanArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun DoubleArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun IntArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun LongArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun FloatArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun ByteArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
fun ShortArray.extendEntries(length: Int) = this.flatMap { x -> List(length) { x } }
```

Is the above a good way to do it if I want to cover arrays?

Exampe usage:

> ```
> val a = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
> println(a.extendEntries(5))
> ```

Outputs:

> ```
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
> ```

Comment: What if you instead did `a.flatMap { it.repeat(5) }` ? it's only 8 characters longer, but much shorter then `flatMap{  x -> List(5) { x } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, yes. If you want users of your library to write `intArrayOf(1, 2, 3).extendEntries(5)` then this is how it is done in Kotlin.

In fact, the Kotlin source code contains methods similar to it, with a specific function for each type of array: (`kotlin.collections._Arrays.kt`)

```
/**
 * Returns a single list of all elements yielded from results of [transform] function being invoked on each element of original array.
 */
public inline fun <R> ShortArray.flatMap(transform: (Short) -> Iterable<R>): List<R> {
    return flatMapTo(ArrayList<R>(), transform)
}

/**
 * Returns a single list of all elements yielded from results of [transform] function being invoked on each element of original array.
 */
public inline fun <R> IntArray.flatMap(transform: (Int) -> Iterable<R>): List<R> {
    return flatMapTo(ArrayList<R>(), transform)
}

/**
 * Returns a single list of all elements yielded from results of [transform] function being invoked on each element of original array.
 */
public inline fun <R> LongArray.flatMap(transform: (Long) -> Iterable<R>): List<R> {
    return flatMapTo(ArrayList<R>(), transform)
}
```

However, Kotlin uses a generator to generate such files, see the README at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/stdlib

In your case, you might consider just implementing `Iterable<T>.extendEntries` as all of these specific types of arrays can be transformed to an `Iterable<T>` using the Kotlin stdlib `.asIterable` function.

Comment: see also: 
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-do-the-primitive-array-classes-need-to-be-exposed/1455?u=tieskedh